# How to call http azure functions via http requests in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, azure

I have one HTTP Post API (build in ASP.NET Core), that API is responsible to add Customer in database.I would like to send an email using Azure function at the time of HTTP Post request. Azure function should automatically get triggered. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you pls clarify what you are interested in? Building AzureFunc or call it from the Asp.Net  Core app? or both )

Comment: Checkout [Azure Functions HTTP trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it important to you that this is achieved by an Azure function?  [Azure Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/logic-apps/) were designed with such workflows in mind.

However, if it's important to you that this is implemented by an Azure Function then you'll need to create a new Azure Function with a [Http Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp).  You'll need to implement the e-mail sending functionality yourself using a library such as [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).

[Here](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/02/using-mailkit-send-receive-email-asp-net-core/)'s a good resource on using MailKit to send e-mails.